# Custom Post Type meta value is being saved in array, instead of just the string (as value)

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, get-posts

So, this is how WordPress is saving my CPT meta:

```
 array(8) {    
 ["product_id"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "abcdefg987" }  
 ["end_date"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "02-02-2015" }  
 }
```

But I want it to be like this:

```
 array(8) {    
 ["product_id"]=>  "abcdefg987" ,
 ["end_date"]=>  "02-02-2015"   
 }
```

So, is it possible ?

---

Here is some of my code:
**to save:**
`update_post_meta($post_id, "end_date", $_POST["end_date"]);`
**The meta box:**

```
global $post;
$custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);  
$end_date = $custom["end_date"][0]; // <- this was an old hack to this problem  
<p><label>End Date:</label><br />  
<input name="end_date" value="<?php echo $end_date; ?>"></input></p>
```

---

**What I really want to do ?**
What I need is to get the Post (custom) with the 'end_date' greater than today. So, I have a meta_query, but doesn't work, cause also shows me the posts with 'end_date' < today, so I thought is because it get its values in the array, and not just the values, here is the code:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'myEventCPT',
    'meta_query' => array(
            array(  'meta_key' => 'end_date',
                    'value' => date("m-d-Y"), // Set today's date 
                    'compare' => '>=', 
                    //'type' => 'DATE'
            )
    )
);  
$my_event_post = get_posts( $args );
```

Comment: Your question, your comments and the question update is confusing and about different things. If your true question is what you describe in the last update (getting posts witha meta field greater than today), please use the search in this site, that question has been asked a lot of times.

Comment: @cybmeta, well yeah, I did discover my true problem while looking for the solution of this problem. I will edit/delete my question promptly. Thanks.

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales your date format is wrong, you need to save it in Y-m-d. Think of it as just comparing 8 digit numbers- 02-24-2015 appears earlier than 03-24-1983, because 2242015 < 3241983.

Comment: @milo, yes you are right !, fixed and now works better, but still, not working properly...

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is not with storage, it is with retrieval. `get_post_custom()` is inconvenient and rarely used in practice.

[`get_post_meta()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_post_meta/) is more common in practice. Note it has explicit argument to retrieve a single value, rather than array of values for a key (which WP can do too).

Comment: This is on the right track. The problem, is that it only works, when I set the second argument to a specific key, so if  I set it to '', it will just return the array of values.

Comment: Yes, this one is meant to work with specific keys. Which is how it actually happens in practice most of the time, retrieving the complete set of custom fields is uncommon (in my experience).

Comment: I see. Well thanks for that !, what I just notice (thanks to you, and other fellows in *Reddit*), is that my problem is not with that specifically,  is with the dates in a *meta_query*, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

THe only possible way is this if your html input name is

name="end_date[]"...

SO can you please check it once more

Comment: Please use the [WYSIWYG](http://xkcd.com/1341/) editor buttons to format your content.

Comment: I don't have `[]` in the name property of the input.

Comment: The problem is with getting the right post data, from a *meta_query* which involves dates. I have edited my question.

Comment: Solved !, thanks for your help. I posted the solution.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I fixed (with the help of everybody, from Reddit, and StackExchange),
I had several issues.
This is my working code:

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'my-cpt',
    'order' => 'ASC' ,
    'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(  'key' => 'end_date',
                    'value' => date("Y-m-d"), //today
                    'compare' => '>=', 
                    'type' => 'DATE'
            ),
            array(  'key' => 'product_id',
                    'value' => $product['id'],
                    'compare' => '=',
                    'type' => 'CHAR'
            ),  
    ),
);
```